# JavaScript - Unable to get names of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have made a JavaScript code to see which checkboxes are checked.

```
<script>
var saveTestValue = function() {
                         var selected = [];
                          $('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
                              selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
                          });

                          alert(selected);
                    };
</script>
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="A"> A
    <input type="checkbox" name="A" value="B"> B
    <input type="submit" value="Save" onsubmit="saveTestValue()">
    </form>
```

Browser is making no alert on calling this script.

Comment: [works for me](http://jsbin.com/zenufaqacona/1/edit?html,output), presumably the code you have for calling the function (which you haven't shared) is wrong.

Comment: Which browser are you testing ? Are you testing in IE ?

Comment: And how are you calling it?

Comment: You're not calling the function. `onsubmit` is fired by a `form` not by an `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onsubmit="saveTestValue()"` should be in `form` element, not with `input` element

```
<form onsubmit="saveTestValue()">
 ....
</form>
```

But you can define `onclick` event with `input` element if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the id "#checkboxes" in the jquery call, but in your form there is no such id.
You should add it like this :

```
    <form id="checkboxes">
```